# SQL.Ошибка во второй строке при отправки таблицы на почту

Tags: sql, gmail

```
    exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'helloWorld',
@recipients = 'adamhodovanets@gmail.com',
@query = 'select * from Shop.dbo.Category' ,
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1, 
@query_attachment_filename = 'CSV_Extract.csv',
@query_result_separator=','
```

Вот такой получается таблица(из-за чего такая 2 строка?):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

select

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выложите, пожалуйста, что возвращает select и содержимое csv файла в текстовом виде.

Comment: Все тоже самое только без 2 строки. Файл:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5cgnAvsnd-uMlNoR1F1YlROSGYza3Q0VUxtTDc1TTdsTUQ4/view?usp=sharing

Comment: То есть, 2-ая  строка лишняя. А теперь откройте полученный csv файл в текстовом редакторе (а не в экселе), и выложите содержимое в текстовом виде.

Comment: Открыл в блокноте 2 строка:

-----------,--------------------------------------------------,-----------,---------------------,-----------,-----------,------------,-----------

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Откройте `Management Studio`
2. откройте пункт меню `Tools->Options`
3. найдите  `Query Results->SQL Server->Results to text`  и в правом
   верхнем углу вместо `Column Aligned` поставьте `Comma delimited`
4. После этого, запустите ваш скрипт с другой вкладки (вкладка
   запоминает настройки).

Все дело в том, что когда выставлен `Column Aligned`, для выделения заголовков и добавляется эта линия.